# Javascript to trigger the collapse/expand content

Tags: html, css, expand

i have a expand content, but how can i use javascript to toogle it to expand the content without clicking it ? i need the content to be display when the page is load.

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/home/common/popup/popup.js"></script>
    <TITLE>headerFrame.jsp</TITLE>
   <script>
   function toogle()
   {
        // how to use javascript to toogle the expand content
   } 
   </script>
  </HEAD>    
  <BODY onload="toogle();">
    <form name="mainfrm" method="post">
      <table style="background-color:#DDDDDD;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible >></a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
              <br/><a href="Javascript:popupWindow( 'https://www.google.com.my/') ">testing content</a>
              <br/>
              <input type="button" value="readMore">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="15% " align="center">TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="40% " align="left " >TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="45% " >TOP FRAME</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Just add " in " class to your collapse div as " <div id="demo" class="collapse in"> "

Answer (score 2):

Just add the class `in` to the div `#demo`.  This will tell bootstrap to have the collapse open by default.

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/home/common/popup/popup.js"></script>
    <TITLE>headerFrame.jsp</TITLE>
   <script>
   function toogle()
   {
        // how to use javascript to toogle the expand content
   } 
   </script>
  </HEAD>    
  <BODY onload="toogle();">
    <form name="mainfrm" method="post">
      <table style="background-color:#DDDDDD;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible >></a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
              <br/><a href="Javascript:popupWindow( 'https://www.google.com.my/') ">testing content</a>
              <br/>
              <input type="button" value="readMore">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="15% " align="center">TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="40% " align="left " >TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="45% " >TOP FRAME</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the 'in' class to div #demo. Example:

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/home/common/popup/popup.js"></script>
    <TITLE>headerFrame.jsp</TITLE>
   <script>
   function toogle()
   {
        // how to use javascript to toogle the expand content
   } 
   </script>
  </HEAD>    
  <BODY onload="toogle();">
    <form name="mainfrm" method="post">
      <table style="background-color:#DDDDDD;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible >></a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
              <br/><a href="Javascript:popupWindow( 'https://www.google.com.my/') ">testing content</a>
              <br/>
              <input type="button" value="readMore">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="15% " align="center">TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="40% " align="left " >TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="45% " >TOP FRAME</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you dont wannt to use the bootstrap class, you can simply call

```
demo.style.display = 'block';
demo.style.height = 'auto';
```

But using the bootstrap class is highly recommended!!!

Hope that helps